# Identifying object fields with strings in Scala

Tags: scala, ecmascript-6

In **ES6** we can refer to a field of an object as:

```
seller['firstname']
```

to represent

```
seller.firstname
```

Is there a way to do the same in Scala? I mean, to use strings to refer to object fields?

Comment: Not sure if I get it right, but you might want to look into [dynamic](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/Dynamic.html)

Comment: What is the use case for this? Don't try to write Scala as if it were JavaScript.

Answer (score 6):

With `Scala 2.13`, you should be able to do something more or less related by using case classes' new [`productElementNames`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.13.x/scala/Product.html#productElementNames:Iterator[String]) method which returns an iterator over its field names.

By zipping field names with field values obtained with [`productIterator`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.13.x/scala/Product.html#productIterator:Iterator[Any]) we can access a case class field value by using the string version of the field name:

```
implicit class CaseClassExtensions(obj: Product) {

  def select[T](field: String): Option[T] =
    (obj.productElementNames zip obj.productIterator)
      .collectFirst { case (`field`, value) => value.asInstanceOf[T] } 
}
```

```scala
// case class Seller(firstName: String, lastName: String)
Seller("Hello", "World").select[String]("firstName")
// Option[String] = Some(Hello)
```

Here, the implicit class is used to enrich the `Product` type (which is case class inherited type) in order to call this `select` method on any case class.

---

But contrary to what you're used to in Javascript:

- This is limited to case classes.
- This returns an `Option` of the value (or you'd have to deal with exceptions when trying to get the value of a field which isn't defined).
- You have to specify the return type of the associated value.

Answer (score 1):

No. I don't think so. As Scala based on JVM which require static type. Unless you want to use [reflection](https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/reflection/overview.html)

Answer (score 1):

The solution from Xavier Guihot would be working from **Scala 2.13**, but you could also implement by-string-access with **shapeless** with **Scala 2.12** or below.

First of all, add **shapeless** to your **build.sbt**:

```
libraryDependencies += "com.chuusai" %% "shapeless" % "2.3.3"
```

We'd need to use *LabelledGeneric* and *ToMap*. We could implement it as an extension class working on case classes:

```
object DynamicAccess {
  implicit class DynamicAccessOps[R <: HList, T <: Product with Serializable](o: T)(
    implicit gen: LabelledGeneric.Aux[T, R],
    toMap: ToMap[R]
  ) {
    private lazy val fields = toMap(gen.to(o))
    def apply[S](field: String): Option[S] = fields
                              .get(Symbol.apply(field).asInstanceOf[toMap.Key])
                              .asInstanceOf[Option[S]]
  }
}
```

Then you could use it like this:

```
import DynamicAccess._

case class Foo(bar: String, baz: String)

val f = Foo("x", "y")

f[String]("bar") // Some(x)
f[String]("baz") // Some(y)
f[String]("foobar") //None
```